# DB2 Hour format

Tags: sql, db2

In my DB2 native Stored Procedure (SP) my current query is :

```
SET QUERY_TS = CURRENT TIMESTAMP -  1 HOUR;
```

"1 hour" is hard coded in the SP and I would like to have it replaced with a variable so that I can get the "hours" required from front end. Please advise me on how to get this working..

Comment: Hm... use a variable in place of the literal?

Comment: I dont want to use literal anymore. The value of the variable will come as input to the stored procedure

Comment: In standard SQL this would be something like `current_timestamp - (interval '1' hour * xxx)` where xxx is the number of hours passed as a variable. I don't know if that would work for DB2 though

Answer (score 0):

Added a variable HRS as an Input INTEGER variable to SP and changed the above query from SET to below and it worked.

```
IN HRS INT;

DECLARE QUERY_TS TIMESTAMP ; 

SELECT (current timestamp - HRS hour) into QUERY_TS FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```